# Is Box and Pierce test on residual or squared residual?

Tags: r, garch, diagnostic

In a GARCH model, is it better to test the autocorrelation of squared residuals rather than the autocorrelation of residuals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A fairly standard assumption of a time series model is that residuals are $i.i.d.$, which excludes autocorrelation for both levels and squares. Hence, in a "good" time series model residuals will not be autocorrelated, whether in levels or in squares.

A GARCH model assumes that *standardized* residuals are $i.i.d.$, where *standardized* residuals are residuals from the conditional mean model divided by fitted conditional standard deviations from the GARCH model. Thus the *standardized* residuals should be autocorrelation-free in both levels and squares.